# How to assign an new observation to existing Kmeans clusters based on nearest cluster centriod logic in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, text-classification

I used the below code to create k-means clusters using Scikit learn.

```
kmean = KMeans(n_clusters=nclusters,n_jobs=-1,random_state=2376,max_iter=1000,n_init=1000,algorithm='full',init='k-means++')

kmean_fit = kmean.fit(clus_data)
```

I also have saved the centroids using `kmean_fit.cluster_centers_`

I then pickled the K means object.

```
filename = pickle_path+'\\'+'_kmean_fit.sav'
pickle.dump(kmean_fit, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

So that I can load the same kmeans pickle object and apply it to new data when it comes, using `kmean_fit.predict().`

**Questions :**

1. Will the approach of loading kmeans pickle object and applying
   `kmean_fit.predict()` allow me to assign the ***new observation to
   existing clusters*** based on centroid of the existing clusters? Does this approach just recluster from scratch on the new data?
2. If this method wont work how to assign the new observation to
       existing clusters given that I already have saved the cluster
       centriods using efficent python code?

PS: I know building a classifer using existing clusters as dependent variable is another way but I dont want to do that because of time crunch.

Comment: Use the source, Luke! Rather than speculating and musing over what might be, just pull open the source and have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Whether the `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` object is pickled or not (**if you un-pickle it correctly, you'll be dealing with the "same" original object**) does not affect that you can use the `predict` method to cluster a new observation.

An example:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.externals import joblib

model = KMeans(n_clusters = 2, random_state = 100)
X = [[0,0,1,0], [1,0,0,1], [0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]
model.fit(X)
```

Out:

```
KMeans(copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_clusters=2, n_init=10,
    n_jobs=1, precompute_distances='auto', random_state=100, tol=0.0001,
    verbose=0)
```

Continue:

```
joblib.dump(model, 'model.pkl')  
model_loaded = joblib.load('model.pkl')

model_loaded
```

Out:

```
KMeans(copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_clusters=2, n_init=10,
    n_jobs=1, precompute_distances='auto', random_state=100, tol=0.0001,
    verbose=0)
```

See how the `n_clusters` and `random_state` parameters are the same between the `model` and `model_new` objects? You're good to go.

Predict with the "new" model:

```
model_loaded.predict([0,0,0,0])

Out[64]: array([0])
```

Comment: My question is little different. Is the kmean_fit object really saving the cluster centriods of existing clusters? Is kmean_fit.predict() finding distance of new observation to all existing cluster centriods and assigning to nearest centriod? I think kmean_fit.predict() is just reclustering the new data based using the kmeans paramters originally used.

Comment: My question is not whether pickling works or not, that trivial for me.

Comment: Check the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L938) for that method. There's a function called `check_is_fitted`, which, as you might imagine, checks whether the `KMeans` object has already been "fit" to some feature matrix `X`. Then the `predict` method checks whether your data is actually test data (using [`_check_test_data`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L860).

Comment: You might also check out the [`_labels_inertia`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L571) method. To answer your question, I think the `predict` method is finding the distance of a new observation to existing cluster centroids (i.e. those that emerged through the `fit` method), *not* re-computing distances (that would happen if you ran `fit` or `fit_predict`).

Comment: @ML_Pro You might be confusing the `fit`, `fit_predict`, and `predict` method. Each method accomplishes a different thing. I would recommend combing over the `KMeans` docs (and perhaps other model docs in scikit-learn).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Sklearn Kmeans documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) using `predict(X, sample_weight=None)` after loading the pickle file with the stored Kmeans model, will predict the closest cluster each sample in X belongs to.

In the vector quantization literature, cluster_centers_ is called the code book and each value returned by predict is the index of the closest code in the code book.

**Practical note!**
Many times people tend to take the clusters labels from `model.labels_`, however in this case of of prediction make sure to use the returned result, such as `pred_y` in the as in the following example:

```
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    import pickle

    # load the model
    model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

    # predict using the loaded model
    pred_y = model.predict(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but kmeans sets a cluster_centers_ parameter when it fits. If you have the centroids you can set it by doing:

kmeans.cluster_centers_ = centroids_init

It should be able to fit after this.